# Workbox conflicting cache entries when running locally in development

Tags: service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

When using the Workbox Webpack Plugin in development mode (locally), I get the following service worker error:

> PrecacheController.mjs:62 Uncaught add-to-cache-list-conflicting-entries: Two of the entries passed to 'workbox-precaching.PrecacheController.addToCacheList()' had the URL undefined but different revision details. Workbox is is unable to cache and version the asset correctly. Please remove one of the entries.

I believe this is happening because, when webpack re-builds, it seems to add static assets twice to the precache call. Once in the `service-worker.js` file, and another in the `precache-manifest.XXX.js` file. Looking at both files I can see the chunk and entry scripts are added in both places, including the `service-worker.js`.

This isn't a problem in production as every build gets wiped and rebuilt from scratch.

Here's my Workbox Webpack Plugin config:

```js
new GenerateSW({
  swDest: '../service-worker.js',
  globDirectory: 'priv/static',
  globPatterns: ['**/*.{js,css,png,jpg,gif,woff2}'],
  runtimeCaching: [
    {
      urlPattern: /^https:\/\/js.intercomcdn.com\/[a-zA-Z0-9-/_.]*(js|woff)/,
      handler: 'NetworkFirst'
    }, {
      urlPattern: /^https:\/\/fonts\.googleapis\.com/,
      handler: 'NetworkFirst',
      options: {
        cacheName: 'google-fonts-stylesheets'
      }
    },
    {
      urlPattern: /^https:\/\/fonts\.gstatic\.com/,
      handler: 'CacheFirst',
      options: {
        cacheName: 'google-fonts-webfonts',
        cacheableResponse: {
          statuses: [0, 200]
        },
        expiration: {
          maxEntries: 5,
          maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, // one year
        }
      }
    },
    {
      urlPattern: /^https:\/\/logo.clearbit.com/,
      handler: 'CacheFirst',
      options: {
        cacheName: 'clearbit-logos',
        cacheableResponse: {
          statuses: [0, 200]
        },
        expiration: {
          maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, // approx one month
        }
      }
    }, {
      urlPattern: /^https:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\//,
      handler: 'NetworkFirst'
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: same for me with `workbox-webpack-plugin 5.1.4` 

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm getting the exact same error

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm getting the exact same error

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm getting the exact same error